# css pseudo class icon move on button click

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a dropdown menu when button click and show a menu.

I have add the icon: > When click on the menu the icon need chance position, the problem is this dosen't comeback...

Someone coulee fix this code in the way when the menu is colse icon comeback normal?

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
     background-color:transparent;
     color: #000;
     padding: 16px 0px 0px 20px;
     font-size: 16px;
     border: none;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 .dropbtn:before {
 content: "\003e";
 color: #000;
 padding-right:10px;
 }
 
 .dropbtn:hover:before {
 content: "\003e";
 display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
   -o-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
   transform: translate(-5px,5px) rotateZ(90deg);
 }

 .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
     background-color: transparent;
     color:#000
 }

 .dropdown {
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     margin:50px 0px;
     width:100%;
     z-index:0
 }

 .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #fff;
     overflow: auto;
     width:100%;
     padding-bottom:40px
 }
 #menu-category{margin:0}
 .dropdown-content a {
     color: #000;
     padding: 12px 0px 0px 60px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     width:100%;
     font-size:14px;
 }
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="work-dd">Work</a><button onclick="myFunction()"   class="dropbtn">Overview</button>
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            ....code of menu...
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you also post your html to give us a complete example of your problem for us to work with?

Comment: @DrewKennedy Sure.

Comment: This seems more like a javascript question since you'll be running an onclick method to get the menu to open.

Comment: ok I add also the JS